# NameError: name 'request' is not defined, in Django forms

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

How do I get the current logged in user in `forms.py`? I am trying to pre-populate the email field of the current user.

```
class ContactMe(forms.Form):
    name                 = forms.CharField(label = "Name")
    email_address        = forms.CharField(label = "Email Address", intital = request.user.email)
    subject              = forms.CharField(label = "Subject")
    message              = forms.CharField(label = "Message", widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': 10, 'rows': 3}))
    additional_comments  = forms.CharField(required = False)
    class Meta:
        model = Contact_me
```

I tried passing request from `views.py` as :

```
contact_form = ContactMe(request.POST or None, request)
```

and then receiving the request inside of class `ContactMe` as :

```
class ContactMe(forms.Form, request):
    name                 = forms.CharField(label = "Name")
    email_address        = forms.CharField(label = "Email Address", intital = **request.user.email**)
    subject              = forms.CharField(label = "Subject")
    message              = forms.CharField(label = "Message", widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': 10, 'rows': 3}))
    additional_comments  = forms.CharField(required = False)
    class Meta:
        model = Contact_me
```

It throws the error `NameError: name 'request' is not defined`. I know request is accessible in `html`, `models.py`, `views.py`. How to get it in `forms.py`?

The `views.py` :

```
def list_posts(request):
    request.session.set_expiry(request.session.get_expiry_age())        # Renew session expire time
    instance_list = Post.objects.all()
    register_form = UserRegisterForm(data=request.POST or None)
    if register_form.is_valid():
        personal.views.register_form_validation(request, register_form)

    login_form = UserLoginForm(request.POST or None)
    if login_form.is_valid() :
        personal.views.login_form_validation(request, login_form)

    feedback_form = FeedbackForm(request.POST or None)
    if feedback_form.is_valid() :
        personal.views.feedback_form_validation(request, feedback_form)

    contact_form = ContactMe(request.POST or None, request)
    if contact_form.is_valid() :
    personal.views.contact_form_validation(request, login_form)

    if request.POST and not(register_form.is_valid() or login_form.is_valid()):
        if request.POST.get("login"):
            return accounts.views.login_view(request)
        else:
            return accounts.views.register_view(request)

    template = 'blog/archives.html'
    dictionary = {

        "object_list"   : content,
        "register_form" : register_form,
        "login_form"    : login_form,
        "feedback_form" : feedback_form,
        "contact_form"  : contact_form,
    }
    return render(request,template,dictionary)
```

Comment: could you show your view?

Comment: @KarolisRyselis : Added `views.py` in question.

Comment: where is this code located: `contact_form = ContactMe(request.POST or None, request)`?

Comment: It's located in `views.py`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to pass the `request` when constructing the form class. At this point there is no request. The request only exists inside your view function. You should, therefore, pass the request in your view function when constructing the form instance. To prepopulate the form, you can use the `initial` keyword of the form constructor. It takes a dictionary of field names and values as input.

Example:

```
#views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django import forms

class TestForm(forms.Form):
    foo = forms.CharField()

def test_form(request):
    form = TestForm(initial=dict(foo=request.<some_property>))
    context = dict(form=form)
    template_name = 'testapp/test.html'
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

Comment: The description helped me a lot. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This line is wrong `class ContactMe(forms.Form, request)`.

(Hint: `request` isn't a base class for your form)

The correct way is to access the `user` in the `__init__` method of the form:

```
class ContactMe(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
         model = Contact_me
         fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        super(ContactMe, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

The corresponding line in the `views.py`:

```
contact_form = ContactMe(request.POST, user=request.user)
```

Comment: I added the above code and it says `super(ContactMe, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)` `NameError: name 'ContactMe' is not defined`. The class is of the same name `ContactMe`

Comment: Are you sure you got the indentation correct? I changed the example to use a `ModelForm` to simplify things.

Comment: Yeah the indent wasn't right. The error is gone. I'm currently logged in, but then, `kwargs` and `args` show empty `{}`.

Comment: And you are sure you are passing the additional argument `ContactMe(request.POST, user=request.user)` when instantiating the form (and are using the correct form?)?

Comment: Yeah, I am using `contact_form = ContactMe(request.POST or None, user = request.user)`. Empty `kwargs` and `args`. I wonder why !

Comment: I tried this all the while.. It still remains empty ! Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Also you get this error if you write **requests** instead of **request**

Example

*in views.py*

```
def all_products(requests):
    products = Product.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'store/home.html', {'products': products})
```

should be:

```
def all_products(request):
    products = Product.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'store/home.html', {'products': products})
```

**This was my issue, that's why I bring it up.**

Comment: changing name from request to requests in line 
return render(request, 'store/home.html', {'products': products})
hope this will work for you as it did for me